# ActiveStorage hook after analyze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

I have pictures attached to a model. Those pictures are analyzed and the EXIF data is saved as metadata on the `ActiveStorage::Blob`.

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :picture
end
```

There is an attribute on this model that I use for sorting the instances called `order_date`. This attribute has to be updated with the EXIF time after the blob got analyzed.

Using paperclip, a `before_commit` callback method was sufficient. With ActiveStorage, I also tried `before_save` and `after_touch` but both are not working.

How can I run code right after the `ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob` has run successfully?

(I want to avoid monkey-patching `ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob`, because it is also performed for other attachments.)

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: What does `AnalyzeJob` do exactly? Does it update anything on the model? If it does, that should trigger a after_save definitely

Comment: This is crucial for me since I want to store the metadata of the file in the model table it self

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find anything official.  I ended up overriding the analyze job since it is very simple anyways.  It looks like below.

```
#/app/jobs/active_storage/analyze_job.rb

class ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob < ActiveStorage::BaseJob
  def perform(blob)
    blob.analyze
    blob.attachments.includes(:record).each do |attachment|
      if attachment.record_type == 'Content'
        record = attachment.record
        record.set_file_info
        record.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: See repo for recent version of the patched job Rails 6.1: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activestorage/app/jobs/active_storage/analyze_job.rb